# application.cfc contains encrypted code

Tags: coldfusion

I've just inherited a rather antiquated ColdFusion system (from the Allaire days) which has an application.cfc containing what looks like encrypted code, as follows.

```
Allaire Cold Fusion Template
Header Size: New VersionÏ{£ z¦7¦¶¸¶ähqØ¤ä8X°É¿Ìò©‰P^qvßNÊÒ‡ùFÍû'ÉÊE´Žå¿ˆpcíå†óÎ”7Žä]±Ï÷f?¼û=ÒÂ“šüù>eÐ×åR™”ÎÓ’Íf#®ëâéÃYÐ¦]ÝišEð§µ¤Ë®ðÐ4~¿xî)ä˜âÂã&ÄƒXDÂ2e".´§ábðyNN6¡I¨´eiÈ"³zñ¤îu ÍP†7ü#›™ú! ØþFtðêt-IÏY¤ae~®ç×7,Ä£oâÿPé    ;b7é{”_)UM‚ýó@g£Ä'žê
```

I've never seen this before in an application file. Has anybody? And if it's encoded, how would one un-encode it?

Comment: Seems to be a similar question to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46594853/coldfusion-file-content-no-longer-readable-when-we-open-the-file-in-an-editor

Comment: It is a .cfm template, encrypted with a very old - and insecure - tool which (I believe) was called cfcrypt.exe. The algorithm is well known, so it's little more than a way to obfuscate code. I'd ask whoever gave it to you for the unencrypted source code.  Though this is about hacked templates, the existing answer applies https://stackoverflow.com/a/14733416/8895292

Comment: If it's a CFC and not a CFM page, it's from Macromedia+ days, not Allaire. Just sayin. ;-)

Comment: @Shawn  yes, you're correct that CFC files didn't exist during Allaire days.  However, the `cfencode.exe` utility still ships with ColdFusion 11 (the version I'm currently using) and interestingly still adds the Allaire header to the encoded files.

Comment: Forgot to add my `<cf_snark>` tags. The fact that a `cfencode` utility that ships with CF11 still includes any text mentioning an owner from _14 years prior_ should tell you everything you need to know about the security level of that encryption. :-/  EDIT - more specifically, text implying that the code hasn't really changed much in 14 years....

Comment: @Shawn, I agree completely.  Some of my coworkers were into using `cfencode` yet I was never a fan as outlined in your points above.  All it did was add a level of insecure obfuscation, or what I like to call "hide the door key under the welcome mat" security. All it did for me was add a level of developer annoyance when needing to determine the source code revision in production.

Comment: @user460114 - Case you run into that sort of thing again, searching on the known header text usually yields some results, ex. "Allaire Cold Fusion Template Header Size: New Version"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I've seen this before.  Your `.cfm` and `.cfc` files were encoded/encrypted using the `cfencode.exe` utility.  Luckily someone wrote a decryption utility for it (my coworker needed it several years ago).  Unfortunately I don't know where he downloaded it or obtained a copy, but from doing some online searches, it appears that the utility is called cfdecrypt 2.0.

You can search for it and download it.  Hopefully this points you in the right direction and gives a good starting point.

Comment: @user460114 - (Insert requisite disclaimer here ;-) Yes, I realize it's old code, but .. keep in mind legality issues. If the code belongs to someone else, it's possible decrypting it may not be legal.

Comment: I found cfdecrypt myself and took a quick glance.  It appeared to need a decryption key.

Comment: I didn't make any presumption of legality/illegality.  However, The OP claims he inherited the code, so I provided him with a course of action on what steps he needs to make in order to decrypt the files.  Also, me personally, I'd proceed with caution regarding sites containing download links.

Comment: Are other files also encrypted? If this is code your company owns and you can't get the original source, I'd decrypt it and ditch the encrypted files. Work with the source. Otherwise, it's going to be pretty impossible for you to maintain. If they aren't your files, try to get the source if you can. Otherwise, I'd recommend getting advice from your legal department before proceeding with decryption.

Comment: @Guest Without knowing more about the codebase the OP's using, the encrypted files could belong to some included CMS or other application. In that case, I'd recommend tracking down the developer and finding out if source is available (if it's needed). If it's not the OP's code, I don't think I'd try decrypting it unless the developer is defunct and there's no other option.

Comment: @Guest - I'm not making any assumptions about the ownership of the code. It may very well belong to his company and they just provided the wrong files. However, when common usage of tool might possibly run afoul of legalities, it's always good to mention that IMO, since the reader may not even be aware of it.

Comment: Dan Bracuk, where did you find yours. I downloaded from a link I found on Google and on running the application got an "Access denied" dialogue message at the end of the extraction process, with a "7-zip" label on the dialogue box,