# Problem that I can't see the source code of a ColdFusion (CFM) file correctly

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I have a problem when I try to open a CFM file using any text editor or ColdFusion Builder the source code is like the picture below!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AWoT.png

Comment: How old is the code in question? I believe there used to be a way to 'encrypt' .cfm files to protect the files from being edited. I am not sure this is still a feature of CF, though.

Answer (score 1):

You have encountered a ColdFusion encrypted source file.  In order to decrypt it, you will need to download the `cfdecrypt` utility which can be found [here](https://github.com/disccomp/cfdecrypt).  Keep in mind this hasn't been updated since 2011, so I can't verify that it will work with newer versions of ColdFusion, but there's no harm in giving it a try.

You can get more background on this by looking at this duplicate question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46594853/coldfusion-file-content-no-longer-readable-when-we-open-the-file-in-an-editor).